# How to display tab bar when navigates to out of tabview controller?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have four tab item (home, user, setting, tools) in my tabbed page.

from home , trying  to navigate some other view controller. But , it navigate as new page. I want to navigate inside tabview controller and  want to display the tab bar item when it goes to next page.  Please advise how to achieve this in tabview controller.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo95F.png [enter image description here][1]

Comment: I don't think you can reliably do what you want, the tab view controller forms part of a navigation pattern that contains the need for other types of view displays within the navigation stack.

Comment: What is your UI hierarchy? You can use a tab bar controller as the root, and a navigation controller which contains the table view controller as one of view controllers of tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UI hierarchy as my comment described, then it will work as you want.

The hierarchy in the storyboard is like this:

[image]

Make sure the tab bar controller is the root. Your table view controller have to be embedded in a navigation controller. Let the navigation controller be the tab  of the tab bar controller.

Comment: @User, Could you please accept my answer? If it is helpful.

Comment: I am unable to upvote ur answer. Its need 15 reputation

Comment: You can mark my answer, it doesn't depend on your reputation. Thanks :). See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: I am using NavigationController as initial viewcontroller and navigate to tabbar bar controller using button. If I click the Title button it returned to navigation controller (initial page) instead of tab bar controller. I want to return  tab bar controller if I click Title Back button . How to overcome this? [Attached image in question]

Comment: @User, just remove the navigation controllers after the tab bar controller.

Comment: If I removed the navigation controller , then tab bar item will not displayed right?

Comment: I mean just remove the navigation controllers which contain the item controller, but leave the item controller there.

Comment: ya I understood. But if I remove the navigation controller ,the tab bar will not displayed when we navigate out tab bar controller. I want the same hierarchy which is mentioned your post and move back to Title page if I click Title Back Button. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: I see, I think you can change the RootViewController in AppDelegate. When you click the button in the first view controller, reset the rootviewcontroller to the tabbarcontroller.